# Error on recordset criteria depend if the key is text or numeric

Tags: excel, t-sql, recordset, jet

I need to extract some data from one table, in the same column I've number or text value.
if I need to extract record until value 100% and I use this string:

```
Select count(TypeTrasp) as nr, 
[DataAttesa KPI2-1] as Data FROM [db_Out$] 
Where TypeTrasp = 'AOG' and [DGR] < 1 group by [DataAttesa KPI2-1]`
```

I receive this error run-time '-2147217913 (80040e07)'

With this string (text key) I retrieve the correct record:

```
select count(TypeTrasp) as nr, 
[DataAttesa KPI2-1] as Data FROM [db_Out$] 
Where TypeTrasp = 'AOG' and [DGR]= 'Out of Time' group by [DataAttesa KPI2-1]`
```

I know that in the text key I need to use 'xxx' but in the number key i can't.

EDIT, I change field name from DGR to 2-1, below the sample of my excel table,
the goal is cont record for each [2-1] criteria

[image: table example.]

Comment: I think this is not concerning tag [tag:excel-vba], sounds more like a question concerning SQL. Where do you extract from and where is the database?

Comment: @Asger I've one worksheet with 20K records, to analize my data I need to count the record by some criteria, first I tried to use COUNTIFS, but the code run in 00:01:47, then I'll try to change way and I test ADODB.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why you don't like my SQL?!?
this is my connection string:
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
outpSh.Select

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, tnk I change the filed name but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)' is related with bad conversions. When you say to have "in the same column I've number or text value." in that column you really have only textual values. In where clause try [DGR] < '1' , with number in quotas.

```
 Select count(TypeTrasp) as nr, 
 [DataAttesa KPI2-1] as Data FROM [db_Out$] 
 Where TypeTrasp = 'AOG' and [DGR] < '1' group by [DataAttesa KPI2-1]`
```

Also, consider the use of TRY_CONVERT(int, [DGR]) to determine if the text is an actual number.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

for edited question try this two queries:

```
    SELECT [DataAttessaKPI2-1] AS data, [TypeTrasp], COUNT([2-1]) AS nr
    FROM [db_Out$]
    GROUP BY [DataAttessaKPI2-1], [TypeTrasp]


    SELECT [TypeTrasp],[2-1],COUNT([DataAttessaKPI2-1]) AS nr
    FROM [db_Out$]
    WHERE [TypeTrasp]='Priority' AND [2-1]='Out of Time'
    GROUP BY [TypeTrasp],[2-1]
```

Results of the first query:

```
    data            TypeTrasp      nr
    19/07/2018          PRIORITY    2
    01/08/2018          STD         1
    03/07/2018          STD         4
    04/07/2018          STD         5
    06/07/2018          STD         1
    16/07/2018          STD         1
    17/07/2018          STD         2
    30/07/2018          STD         1
```

Results of second query (with WHERE clause):

```
    TypeTrasp   2-1                 nr
    PRIORITY    Out of Time         2
```